# .net core 2 Google Authentication login loop

Tags: authentication, asp.net-core-2.0

I am trying to authenticate using google in .net core 2 and have done what seems to be the very simple set up required for this:

1) Added `app.UseAuthentication();` to `Configure(..)` in startup.cs

2) Added to `ConfigureServices(..)` startup.cs

```
services.AddAuthentication(options =>
{
    options.DefaultScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    options.DefaultChallengeScheme = GoogleDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
})
.AddCookie()
.AddGoogle(options =>
{
    options.ClientId = Configuration["auth:google:clientid"];
    options.ClientSecret = Configuration["auth:google:clientsecret"];
});
```

Added the appropriate values to my `appsettings.json` for the id and secret that I got from Google Dev.

Added a **web-api** controller with an `[Authorize]` attribute.

Done the appropriate stuff in google dev to set the Authorised JavaScript origins to `http://localhost:50741` (my root) and Authorised redirect URIs to `http://localhost:50741/signin-google`

#### Result

Going to the secured controller endpoint results in a redirect to the google webpage where I can choose a google profile, I choose one and it redirects back to `http://localhost:50741/signin-google` and then immediately back to the google profiles screen creating an infinite loop.

Where have I gone wrong?

Comment: I tried it using IIS Express with SSL on and it's the same problem

Answer (score 1):

It all works fine if I change the `[Authorize]` attribute to `[Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)]`

Comment: Don't ask me why, cos at the moment I dont know :), I will open a new question with regards to this.