# Why does dotnet core [Authorize] require a scheme when a default is set

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core-2.0, .net-core-2.0

I have set up authentication with dotnet core 2.0 like so:

1) Added `app.UseAuthentication();` to `Configure(..)` in startup.cs

2) Added to `ConfigureServices(..)` startup.cs

```
services.AddAuthentication(options =>
{
    options.DefaultScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    options.DefaultChallengeScheme = GoogleDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
})
.AddCookie()
.AddGoogle(options =>
{
    options.ClientId = Configuration["auth:google:clientid"];
    options.ClientSecret = Configuration["auth:google:clientsecret"];
});
```

If I then drop an [Authorize] attribute on my web-api controller it will challenge me to google, I choose an account and it loops forever.

The fix I have found ([.net core 2 Google Authentication login loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48212025/net-core-2-google-authentication-login-loop/48287665#48287665)) is to specify a AuthenticationScheme like so:

`[Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes = GoogleDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)]` or `[Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)]`

(Weirdly `:to-me:` both work in this case)

However I am unsure as to why it is needed when I have specified a default scheme.

If the default scheme is not related, can I specify a default scheme as I don't want to have to specify it each time I use the attribute.

Answer (score 0):

Just add this and it will authorize all the controllers/methods except those with [AllowAnonymous] :

```
services.AddMvc(config =>
{
    var policy = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder()
                     .RequireAuthenticatedUser()
                     .Build();
    config.Filters.Add(new AuthorizeFilter(policy));
});
```

Comment: This does apply the `Authorize` attribute to everywhere but still causes the redirect loop that I describe above.